# Magento Navigation Menu - Sub Navigation

Tags: magento2, php, theme, navigation

I have a template that I'm trying to edit the navigation menu for. I'm able to create sub-menu by this code of line (which is located in topmenu.html

## ">

#">

```
            <span>Knowledge</span>
            <ul class="level0">
                <?php echo $_menu ?>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
```

That links the menu to my category, which then I'm able to edit in magento and add sub-menu category. I'm trying to create another submenu that links to my category in Magento, but does not duplicate the same submenu in Knowledge. Not sure if I explained that correctly, but any help or questions to further understand would be appreciated.

Comment: You can go to the website http://www.brothas.online to see a example. Under the menu Knowledge I have a sub-menu. Looking to create the same thing under for ex: Support, but not be the same sub categories at Knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help above. It allowed me to look at the code more thorough to add what I wanted. Here is what I did

```
<li><a class="category" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>manufacturer.html">
            <span>Support</span>
                            <ul class="level0">
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>help"><span>Help</a></li>
            </ul>
                      </a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just manually build it by inserting code like this into the root `<ul>` element

```
<li class="level0 level-top parent ui-component">
   <span>Support</span>
   <ul class="level0 submenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
      <li class="level1 first ui-menu-item"><span>Item 1</span></li>
      <li class="level1 ui-menu-item"><span>Item 2</span></li>
      <li class="level1 last ui-menu-item"><span>Item 3</span></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: ` <li><a class="category" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>manufacturer.html">
    <span>Support</span>
                                <ul class="level0">
   <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>help"><span>Help</a></li>
    </ul>
                          </a>
    </ul>